Can I create a clickable hyperlink in a pdf using R magick?
I am using R and magick to create infographics as a PDF and want to inset a clickable hyperlink in the resultant PDF output.
Is this possible to do within magick?
Is there another option where I reload the PDF and insert the hyperlink on that and resave.
(most search results seem to end up pointing to me needing to create a markdown document which doesn't seem a very good way of going about things)
Demo code:
library(magick)
url<-"https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/205/2054680838884300340/jpeg-600/G03.jpg"

#Load Graphic
pb<-image_read(url)

#Place text at at top corner
car<-image_draw(pb) %>% 
  image_annotate(paste("I want this to be a clickable hyperlink to:",url),location=geometry_point(10,10), color = "red", size = 10)

#Save PDF
image_write(car,"Car.pdf",format="pdf")

I want to create something like this


I am not sure if the magick package in R supports embedding clickable hyperlinks directly into images or PDFs. rmarkdown is probably the way to go.
library(rmarkdown)
library(magick)

# Loading the image
url <- "https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/205/2054680838884300340/jpeg-600/G03.jpg"
image <- image_read(url)
image_path <- "hyperlink_image.png"
image_write(image, path = image_path)

# Markdown file
rmd_content <- "
---
title: 'Hyperlink in PDF'
output: pdf_document
---

![Car Image]({image_path})

[Click here to go to the link](https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/205/2054680838884300340/jpeg-600/G03.jpg)
"

rmd_content <- gsub("\\{image_path\\}", image_path, rmd_content)


rmd_file <- "hyperlink_rmd_file.Rmd"
writeLines(rmd_content, con = rmd_file)

# Render PDF
render(input = rmd_file, output_format = "pdf_document", output_file = "output.pdf")


Thanks - is there a method that you would recommend to place the hyperlink(s) in particular places over the image in Markdown - the method you provided just provides a link in a text document to the online image, not the placing of the hyperlink over the image.
As I can insert an image in the comment - I have added one in the original post...

So, in particular, I am being asked to replicate the red hyperlinks in this document that appear when you rollover the panels with the pumps, the car or the graph....
https://www.racfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/RACF-fuel-fact-sheet.pdf

This will create a hyperlink over the image.
---
title: 'Hyperlink in PDF'
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \\usepackage{hyperref}
---
\\begin{figure}[h]
\\centering
\\href{https://atlas-content-cdn.pixelsquid.com/assets_v2/205/2054680838884300340/jpeg-600/G03.jpg}{
  \\includegraphics[width=1\\textwidth]{hyperlink_image.png}
}
\\caption{Click on the image to go to the link}
\\end{figure}
"

As for placing multiple hyperlinks over the image, you will have to use LaTex positioning boxes to manual position the links.

You gave an example of buttons in a glossy publication, and I suggest you do not bother to emulate that ever so carbon unfriendly method. There are 6 such buttons inside that file and each consumes many KB of memory just sitting there. So the file with the shiny chromium plated (unfriendly to accessibility) buttons should be sent to the scrap yard and replaced by a less bytes per hyperlink model.
Here is one trimmed to the absolute bone and then it's still over 1 KB. It does not work in every viewer, it cannot be heard by the poor of sight. Basically universally better when replaced by a very simple hyperlink.

%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj <</AcroForm 2 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>> endobj 
2 0 obj <</Fields[4 0 R]>> endobj 
3 0 obj <</Count 1/Kids[5 0 R]/Type/Pages>> endobj 
4 0 obj <</AA<</D<</S/URI/URI(https://www.example.com)>>>>/AP<</N 6 0 R/R 7 0 R>>/Border[0 0 0]/C[]/F 4/Ff 65536/FT/Btn/H/P/MK<</I 6 0 R/IF<</FB true/SW/N>>/RI 7 0 R/TP 1>>/P 5 0 R/Rect[5 5 295 195]/Subtype/Widget/T(Button 1)/Type/Annot>> endobj 
5 0 obj <</Annots[4 0 R]/MediaBox[0 0 300 200]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 9 0 R>> endobj  
6 0 obj <</BBox[0 200 300 0]/Subtype/Form/Length 0/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]/Resources<<>>>> stream
endstream
endobj 
7 0 obj <</BBox[0 200 300 0]/Subtype/Form/Length 141/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS0 8 0 R>>/Font<</F0/Helvetica>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text]>>>> stream
BT /CS0 cs 0.686 0.016 0.261 scn /GS0 gs /F0 1 Tf 0 Tc 0 Tw 0 Ts 100 Tz 0 Tr 10 0 0 10 180 190 Tm
[(\(Click for more information\)  )]TJ
ET
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj <</AIS false/BM/Normal/ca 1/CA 1/OP false/op false/OPM 1/SA true/SMask/None/Type/ExtGState>> endobj 
9 0 obj <</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000077 00000 n 
0000000112 00000 n 
0000000164 00000 n 
0000000411 00000 n 
0000000520 00000 n 
0000000633 00000 n 
0000000954 00000 n 
0000001063 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 10/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
1115
%%EOF

The additional bloat (not shown) is mainly due to embedding large ICColour profile tables (for an invisible button!!), and related font styles!
Answer
Several command line tools can add a hyper text at a given location in a post compilation stage. You will need to test where to overlay the URL action during placing the body text then apply each URL to each location.
Typical PDF applications with such ability are coherent cpdf and pdfcpu but there are others. HOWEVER since you're especially crafting one per text placement, I would use a GUI editor as much faster for cut, paste and at same time test such custom links. Thus the most efficient use of your company's paid time.

